# If forward slash(/) followed by multiple forward slashes replace only the first one each occurrence

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a single occurrence of forward slash(/) with an empty string. If a forward slash(/) is followed by multiple forward slash (/) I want to replace only the first slash with an empty string.

Sample input:

CASE 1:

```
input: "This is /text/"
output: "This is text"
```

CASE 2:

```
input: "This// is //text"
output: "This/ is /text"
```

By using regex how we can replace in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By capturing any following forward slashes *after* the first one, we can simply replace a string of forward slashes by the capture group i.e. search for

```
/(/*)
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B4Uofj/1)

In Java:

```
String input = "This is /text/";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("/(/*)", "$1"));
input = "This// is //text";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("/(/*)", "$1"));
```

Output:

```
This is text
This/ is /text
```